# I want my object to continue moving but it won't work

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want it to keep moving with the assigned speed, but it just moves once and it stops.
I thought the after function would help but it doesnt..
Also I want to know what the number does inside the after brackets

```
    import tkinter as tk

    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000, background='black')
    canvas.pack()

    circle = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 10, 10, fill='white')

    def move():
        canvas.move(circle, 100, 100)

    move()
    canvas.after(40, move())


    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Widget.after-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass only function name in `after()` as below...

```
canvas.after(40, move)
```

Instead of...

```
canvas.after(40, move())
```

Mean after 40 milliseconds `after()` function will be call and then your object will be move.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `after(...)` inside `move()`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=1000, background='black')
canvas.pack()

circle = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 10, 10, fill='white')

def move():
    canvas.move(circle, 10, 10)
    canvas.after(50, move)

move()

root.mainloop()
```

Refer [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) on how to use `after()` function.

Comment: It's not working.. OHOFJOWJFIOAWODKWADMW i legit did everything the internet told me to do but its not working.. maybe my computer is weird????

Comment: Yes I tested it on my pycharm program and it didn't move at all. But I tested your code on an online tkinter runner and it worked. I think my pycharm is the problem..